# ldapjs-client V0.1.0 bind method throwing UnwillingToPerformError after working fine for few days

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, ldapjs, fastify

I am facing a weired issue on *ldapjs-client V0.10.0 with fastify V1.1.1*

Below snippet working fine for couple of day. Suddenly throwing **UnwillingToPerformError**. It is working  fine if we restart the server again,error is same after couple of days.

```
const authClient = new LdapClient({
      url: config.ldap.url,
      tlsOptions: tlsOptions,
      timeout: 5000,
      connectTimeout: 1000
})
var userDN = 'uid=' + username + ',ou=test,dc=test,dc=test'
await authClient.bind(userDN, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

UnwillingToPerform is a server side error, most likely because the server has ran out of resources, such as file descriptors. You might want to check in your code if you are closing the LDAP connections.